# Making calls without ACTION_CALL activity

Tags: android, phone-call

Is there a way to make a call from my application, but keep my activity in focus?  `ACTION_CALL` shows the call screen, but I want to show my screen instead, with my own control to end the call.  Is this possible?  e.g. is there a service that does the actual phone call?

I basically want to allow the user to call another user, while still interacting with my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change or customize the call screen unless you are building your own ROM

That is not possible from an SDK application...

You can try to design your application so that it works with a backgroud service so that you achieve your goals